# Making a Network Connection Simulation for avoiding programs that use the internet disconnect after the dialup connection is momentarily closed

Tags: java, php, c++, c, delphi

Making a Network Connection Simulation for avoiding programs that use the internet disconnect after the dialup connection is momentarily closed

Because its like this, since I do some stuff that requires resetting the Dial UP PPPOE connection of my computer in order to change the IP, I have to disconnect and connect again so it refreshes the IP, so now I need a program that makes a fake ethernet connection just so the programs think that the connection is just a little slow, and when I reconnect the internet (which is fast in around 3 ~ 5 seconds disconnecting and connecting again) the ethernet uses the dial up pppoe connection again, so the programs that is using the internet are back on without thinking that you were disconnected. programs like MSN Messenger, Google Talk, Youtube Videos in flash doesn't break completely, just wait a while till the internet is back on again.

it can be in any language, doesn't matter. Java, C, C++, C#

is there anything like that? I use windows 7 and windows xp,
Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is a virtual PPP interface, when the applications you're cited don't explicitly check PPP. In which case, a VPN that tunnels all connections from your machine would be preferred, since your applications would still see an available route that was temporarily blackholing your connections.

This might be a better question on https://serverfault.com/ or https://superuser.com/, given the requisite needs to set up the virtual interface and configure your machines to use it, respectively.

Comment: hm thank you very much for replying this is not very clear to me though, is there any tutorial to look for, if you have a beginner's tutorial for this subject I would be very pleased, or if you know any program that helps you do it, I would be glad. is there any post anywhere that people are discussing that?, The problem for me to search is that I'm not very sure how to search since it doesn't have (or I don't know) a specific name, Thank you in advance!